# ASP.NET 3.1 Web API, Entity Framework one to many relationship either not made or ending in cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So I am trying to write a server with a database which would host a site similar to reddit: with users, groups, posts and comments.

As this is my first time developing backend, I tried googling and found ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API with Entity Framework to be "good". (I use SQL Server as the database server if that's relevant)

Now I went with the code first method, and created the tables with a migration.
([ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXECE.png))

I used the built in tool to create the controllers.

If I used this JSON to create a post entity (with HTTP POST), the AuthorId and the LocationId stay on NULL (weather I use "" for the numbers or not). I created the Group and the User it would refer to earlier.

The JSON:

```
{
    "title": "Post",
    "posttext": "text",
    "creatorid": "1",
    "locationid": "1",
    "timeofpost": "2020-01-12"
}
```

The Post class:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace CedditBackend.Models
    {
        public class Post
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
    #nullable enable
            public string? PostText { get; set; }
            public byte[]? Content { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Comment>? Comments { get; set; }
    #nullable disable
            public User Creator { get; set; }
            public Group Location { get; set; }
            public DateTime TimeOfPost { get; set; }

        }
    }
```

The autogenerated HTTPPOST in the controller:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult<Post>> PostPost(Post post)
            {
                _context.Posts.Add(post);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return CreatedAtAction("GetPost", new { id = post.Id }, post);
            }
```

On the other hand if I try and create my own post class from the JSON (basically deserializing it), I get an error that "a cycle was detected". This I tried googling, but only found that with an earlier version (I guess) I could just turn that off.

Still if I open the database, it shows me that the values of LocationId and AuthorId are not NULL, but if I try to get the posts of the Users (with an HTTP GET), all I get is the same error message.

My rewritten HTTPPOST

```cs
    [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult<Post>> PostPost(Object obj)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(obj.ToString());

                Post post = new Post();
                post.Title = dict["title"].ToString();
                post.PostText = dict["posttext"].ToString();
                post.TimeOfPost = DateTime.Parse(dict["timeofpost"].ToString());
                post.Location = _context.Groups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == int.Parse(dict["locationid"].ToString()));
                post.Creator = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == int.Parse(dict["creatorid"].ToString()));

                post.Creator.Posts.Add(post);
                post.Location.Posts.Add(post);

                _context.Posts.Add(post);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return CreatedAtAction("GetPost", new { id = post.Id }, post);
            }
```

I tried to google this whole stuff in several ways, but found nothing. Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: the User class (which I think causes the cycle reference)

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CedditBackend.Models
{

        public class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string UserName { get; set; }
    #nullable enable
            public ICollection<Post>? Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
            public ICollection<Comment>? Comments { get; set; } = new List<Comment>();
            public ICollection<UserGroup>? UserGroups { get; set; }
    #nullable disable

        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running into the same problem I currently have.

The new JSON library [System.Text.JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) is currently unable to handle One-to-Many relationships it seems. They are currently tracking the issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/41002), but a fix isn't planned until .NET 5. I haven't found a solution at this point but I will update this answer if I do.

**UPDATE**
Found a workaround, at least for now.

Install Newtonsoft MVC Extensions

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.1.1
```

Edit ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson()
```

Now configure the loop handling in Newtonsoft

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
      options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
          Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

That should be enough to get it working. Keep in mind if you have any custom JsonConverters you will have to change to the converters provided in the Newtonsoft library to get them to work.

Comment: It's working just fine, thank you! I was just about to write it myself, as I understood the problem, but this is a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing these lines.

```
post.Creator.Posts.Add(post);
post.Location.Posts.Add(post);
```

You've already defined the Creator and Location of your post. Adding it to their collections would make it a circular reference.

Comment: I still throws the same error. If I debug it, it will go just fine until the return in the HTTPPOST, but after that it goes into User, from which it goes into Post and so on..